# Simple Image Gallery inlucde code in Custom HTML module

Tags: joomla-3.x

When I try to include Simple Image gallery inside Custom HTML module, i don't get the gallery like in an Article.
I use this code:
{gallery}images/gallery/second{/gallery}

An all it gets displayed is this code, but not he gallery content. What am I missing? In  an article the gallery content is shown normally.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the developer of Simple Image Gallery for support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into your module that you are pasting the code into, select the options tab and then turn on "prepare content".

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it worked. Thank you very much.